# Customized the icons of Menu items

Tags: android, xml

Hi,
I would like to know how can I customized Menu icons. For instance, if the menu option is "Save" I want to put custom image rather than default image. 
Hope it is clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the [`setIcon()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setIcon%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) function of [`MenuItem`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html).  It can accept either a `Resource` ID or a `Drawable`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but for example if I write the following it gives me an error: item2.setIcon(android.R.drawable.icon); icon is an image icon.PNG.under Drawable folder. Why show this error? please help me :(\

Comment: android.R is for built-in Android framework resources. Use your own app's R constants to refer to your app's resources.

Comment: Just use it in the form `R.drawable.icon` which will use the one in your drawable folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
MenuItem item;
        item.setIcon(icon);            // icon is Drawable icon
        item.setIcon(resIcon);         // resIcon is int resIcon
```